# How to obtain symmetrical matrix from dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, data-manipulation

I have a basic question about data manipulation in Python.

I have the following dictionary:

```
mydict={('A', 'E'): 23972,
 ('A', 'D'): 10730,
 ('A', 'B'): 14748,
 ('A', 'C'): 3424,
 ('E', 'D'): 3294,
 ('E', 'B'): 16016,
 ('E', 'C'): 3373,
 ('D', 'B'): 69734,
 ('D', 'C'): 4662,
 ('B', 'C'): 159161}
```

If you look carefully, this is half of a symmetrical matrix with null diagonal (the 0s are not included). My final goal is to write a pandas dataframe with the full matrix.

**Tentative solution**

I thought about "unpacking" the dictionary obtaining 5 lists, one per label, with all the values related to the other labels, adding a 0 on the self-position of the list. For label "A" and "B", the desired result would be:

```
A=[0,mydict(['A','B']),mydict(['A','C']),mydict(['A','D']),mydict(['A','E'])]
B=[mydict(['A','B']),0,mydict(['B','C']),mydict(['D','B']),mydict(['E','B'])]
```

and so on for C,D,E. Notice that, in B, 4th and 5th elements are mydict(['D','B']) and mydict(['E','B']), because mydict(['B','D']) and mydict(['B','E']) simply don't exist in mydict.

This way I could easily populate a dataframe from these lists:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
df['A']=A
df['B']=B
```

**Question**

I am not quite sure about how I can "unpack" mydict into those lists, or into any other container that could help me building the matrix. Any suggestions?

Comment: added benchmarks in my answer

Comment: thanks everyone! all answers are working, I chose the first one simply because it came first and it is elegant and efficient. also thanks akshay for the benchmarks.

Comment: I would recommend keeping an upvote for that. the correct solution is one which is the best, and not the first. selecting the best comment as the correct helps the community find the correct answer when they face an issue like this. SO is a community maintained platform and therefore its important to contribute from that perpective. As you gain more reputation, you get the ability to edit other's questions/answers, evaluate incorrect and low quality solutions etc. Its important to contribute accordingly therefore.

Comment: my solution was the slowest, and in no way the best, therefore even if I had commented the first, i should never get the correct solution because it is not. Still, i contributed with a benchmark so that at least those looking for the right answer are able to refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to reconstruct the dictionary in full matrix format and then pivot it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
mydict={('A', 'E'): 23972,
 ('A', 'D'): 10730,
 ('A', 'B'): 14748,
 ('A', 'C'): 3424,
 ('E', 'D'): 3294,
 ('E', 'B'): 16016,
 ('E', 'C'): 3373,
 ('D', 'B'): 69734,
 ('D', 'C'): 4662,
 ('B', 'C'): 159161}
 
 
# construct the full dictionary
newdict = {}

for (k1, k2), v in mydict.items():
    newdict[k1, k2] = v
    newdict[k2, k1] = v
    newdict[k1, k1] = 0
    newdict[k2, k2] = 0

# pivot the result from long to wide
pd.Series(newdict).reset_index().pivot(index='level_0', columns='level_1', values=0)

#level_1      A       B       C      D      E
#level_0                                     
#A            0   14748    3424  10730  23972
#B        14748       0  159161  69734  16016
#C         3424  159161       0   4662   3373
#D        10730   69734    4662      0   3294
#E        23972   16016    3373   3294      0
```

Or as commented by @Ch3steR, you can also just do `pd.Series(newdict).unstack()` for the pivot.

[Demo link](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/93ca28b5.py)

Comment: jeez, that was clever, thanks a lot! the trick is in the smart usage of pivot, I still can't get the hang of (un)pivot functions.

Comment: `pd.Series(newdict).unstack()` would also give desired output. Cool answer tho +1

Comment: @Ch3steR Great alternative.

Answer (score 3):

What I can think of is populate the dict values to an array first then construct dataframe.

```py
mydict={('A', 'E'): 23972,
 ('A', 'D'): 10730,
 ('A', 'B'): 14748,
 ('A', 'C'): 3424,
 ('E', 'D'): 3294,
 ('E', 'B'): 16016,
 ('E', 'C'): 3373,
 ('D', 'B'): 69734,
 ('D', 'C'): 4662,
 ('B', 'C'): 159161}
 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.full((5,5),0)
ss = 'ABCDE'

for k, i in mydict.items():
    f,s = k 
    fi = ss.index(f)
    si = ss.index(s)
    a[fi,si] = i
    a[si,fi] = i

# if you want to keep the diagonal
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

# if you want to remove diagonal:
no_diag = np.delete(a,range(0,a.shape[0]**2,(a.shape[0]+1))).reshape(a.shape[0],(a.shape[1]-1))

df = pd.DataFrame(no_diag)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straight forward solution which should not take too much time to run as well -

```
cols = np.unique(list(mydict.keys())).ravel()

df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=cols, index=cols)

for i in mydict.items():
    df.loc[i[0]] = i[1] 

df = df + df.T
print(df)
```

```
       A       B       C      D      E
A      0   14748    3424  10730  23972
B  14748       0  159161  69734  16016
C   3424  159161       0   4662   3373
D  10730   69734    4662      0   3294
E  23972   16016    3373   3294      0
```

---

**Benchmarks**

Adding Benchmarks (303 length input, MacBook pro 13)-

```
kk = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSUVWXYZ'
mydict = {i:np.random.randint(1,10000) for i in itertools.combinations(kk,2)}
len(mydict)
#303
```

- *fusion's approach* - 392 µs ± 16.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
- *Psidom's approach* - 4.95 ms ± 286 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- *Akshay Sehgal's approach* - 34.8 ms ± 884 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
- *Ben.T's approach* - 4.01 ms ± 282 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Fusion's approach is the fastest by a long shot.

Comment: your benchmark is interesting and it actually make sense that fusion's approach is faster on a mydict of length 300. try with kk = range(100), even if fusion's approach could still be faster, the difference should not be as big :)

Comment: agreed, your approach stands second plus I found it to be quite innovative as well.

Answer (score 1):

once create a serie form the dictionary and then `unstack` to get a dataframe. Get `union` of index and columns to be able to `reindex` both with all possible values. Add the transpose of this dataframe to itself for missing values.

```
df_ = pd.Series(mydict).unstack(fill_value=0)
idx = df_.index.union(df_.columns)
df_ = df_.reindex(index=idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0)
df_ += df_.T

print(df_)
       A       B       C      D      E
A      0   14748    3424  10730  23972
B  14748       0  159161  69734  16016
C   3424  159161       0   4662   3373
D  10730   69734    4662      0   3294
E  23972   16016    3373   3294      0
```